# Windows Docker Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: mysql, windows, docker

I have a project on windows Docker, when I run the `docker-compose up`, it gives me the bellow error

> php_1      | Database tma not reachable at host: localhost for user: drupal
>   php_1      | ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Here is the docker-compose.yml

```
    version: "3"

services:
  mariadb:
    image: wodby/mariadb:$MARIADB_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mariadb"
    stop_grace_period: 30s
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
      MYSQL_USER: $DB_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - ./dev_tools/mariadb-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d # Place init .sql file(s) here.

  php:
    image: wodby/drupal-php:$PHP_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_php"
    environment:
      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
#      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S opensmtpd:25      
      DB_HOST: $DB_HOST
      DB_PORT: $DB_PORT
      DB_USER: $DB_USER
      DB_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
      DB_NAME: $DB_NAME
      DB_DRIVER: $DB_DRIVER
      PHP_FPM_USER: wodby
      PHP_FPM_GROUP: wodby
      COLUMNS: 80 # Set 80 columns for docker exec -it.
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/
    command: sh /var/www/html/dev_tools/php-entrypoint.bash

  apache:
    image: wodby/apache:$APACHE_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_apache"
    depends_on:
      - php
    environment:
      APACHE_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      APACHE_BACKEND_HOST: php
      APACHE_VHOST_PRESET: php
      APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/html/docroot
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_apache.rule=Host(`${PROJECT_BASE_URL}`)"
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to expose the port at some point?

Comment: @Nae sorry don't get your mean!

Comment: As far as I know container needs to expose the port the host if it's to be accessed from the host. Maybe that's not the case here though.

Comment: `DB_HOST: $DB_HOST` should be container name `mariadb`